# How to draw a tree like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a horizontal tree. A simplified version has one parent, two children with Bezier curves connecting with their parent.

Now I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 1mm]    
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{1mm}{1mm}};
    \node (n1) at (30mm, 0) [rectangle, draw] {First Child};
    \node (n2) at (30mm, 10mm) [rectangle, draw] {Second Child};
    \node (n3) at (0, 5mm) [rectangle, draw] {Parent};
    % \draw (n3.east) .. controls +(((n3.east.x + n1.west.x)/2, n3.east.y)) and +(((n3.east.x + n1.west.x)/2, n1.west.y)) .. (n1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have some questions:

1. Node n1 and n2 are centering aligned. How to align them to the left?
2. The commented line is to draw a Bezier curve that connects n3 and n2. I wanted to calculate two middle positions at specific positions, but I don't know how to make it work.
3. How to know the exact bounding boxes of a text and the whole node? I want them to do extra calculations and drawings.

Comment: Regarding 1., you are referring to the text of the node?

Comment: You find all answers in the two manuals at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . Look for graph (which is one way to do it) and for bend .

Comment: @EduardoAlvesdaSilva I want the whole nodes to be left aligned. If they do, the text is left aligned anyway.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks, I will read it

Comment: @landings You can add "anchor=west" in the node options (next to the "draw" option), which will solve the first question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=.5;}]
\path[nodes={draw,rounded corners,inner sep=1.5mm}]
(0,0)  node[fill=orange!50] (P) {Parents}
(2,-a) node[right,fill=yellow!50] (C1) {First Child}
(2,a)  node[right,fill=yellow!50] (C2) {Second Child}
;
\draw[->] (P) to[out=0,in=180] (C1);
\draw[->] (P) to[out=0,in=180] (C2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You may like to use `controls` to control `shooting forces`

```
\draw[->] (P.0) .. controls +(0:1.2) and +(180:1.2) .. (C1.180);
\draw[->] (P.0) .. controls +(0:1.2) and +(180:1.2) .. (C2.180);
```

[image]

or this (`M` is the midway)

[image]

```
\path (P.0)--(P-|C1.180) coordinate[midway] (M);
\draw[-stealth] (P.0)--(M)|-(C1.180);
\draw[-stealth] (P.0)--(M)|-(C2.180);
```